# Cannot read property 'pm2_env' of undefined

Tags: yarnpkg

I got `Cannot read property 'pm2_env' of undefined` error when I try to run React project by `yarn dev`. 
I've tried deleting node_modules, updating pm2, re-installing and deleting cache of yarn etc.

Answer (score 9):

This is how I solved it -

1. Run `pm2 update`. Make sure you have the updated version - `npm install pm2@latest -g` before running update
2. If that still doesn't work, your processes are most likely stuck. Get rid of the pm2 processes, restart it and it should work fine
   `ps -ef | grep pm2`
   `kill -9 <PID_OF_PM2>`